# Using Facebook's Fresco to load a bitmap

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap, picasso, fresco

I'm trying to replace Picasso in my android app with Fresco. However I am unsure of how to simply load a bitmap using Fresco.

With Picasso I would just do the following.

```
Bitmap poster = Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(url)
                    .resize(Utils.convertDpToPixel(WIDTH,HEIGHT))
                    .centerCrop()
                    .get();
```

I have been unable to figure out how to create a Bitmap with this Fresco. Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK There is no straight way to swap this libraries since Fresco doesn't rely on the standard Bitmap class but rather in their own implementation.

Answer (score 22):

As Fresco said:

If your request to the pipeline is for a decoded image - an Android Bitmap, you can take advantage of our easier-to-use BaseBitmapDataSubscriber:

```
dataSource.subscribe(new BaseBitmapDataSubscriber() {
    @Override
    public void onNewResultImpl(@Nullable Bitmap bitmap) {
       // You can use the bitmap in only limited ways
      // No need to do any cleanup.
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailureImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
      // No cleanup required here.
    }
  },
  executor);
```

You can not assign the bitmap to any variable not in the scope of the onNewResultImpl method.

http://frescolib.org/docs/datasources-datasubscribers.html#_

My code :

```
public void setDataSubscriber(Context context, Uri uri, int width, int height){
    DataSubscriber dataSubscriber = new BaseDataSubscriber<CloseableReference<CloseableBitmap>>() {
        @Override
        public void onNewResultImpl(
                DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableBitmap>> dataSource) {
            if (!dataSource.isFinished()) {
                return;
            }
            CloseableReference<CloseableBitmap> imageReference = dataSource.getResult();
            if (imageReference != null) {
                final CloseableReference<CloseableBitmap> closeableReference = imageReference.clone();
                try {
                    CloseableBitmap closeableBitmap = closeableReference.get();
                    Bitmap bitmap  = closeableBitmap.getUnderlyingBitmap();
                    if(bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
                        //you can use bitmap here
                    }
                } finally {
                    imageReference.close();
                    closeableReference.close();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailureImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
            Throwable throwable = dataSource.getFailureCause();
            // handle failure
        }
    };
    getBitmap(context, uri, width, height, dataSubscriber);
}

/**
 *
 * @param context
 * @param uri
 * @param width          
 * @param height         
 * @param dataSubscriber
 */
public void getBitmap(Context context, Uri uri, int width, int height, DataSubscriber dataSubscriber){
    ImagePipeline imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline();
    ImageRequestBuilder builder = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri);
    if(width > 0 && height > 0){
        builder.setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(width, height));
    }
    ImageRequest request = builder.build();
    DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>
            dataSource = imagePipeline.fetchDecodedImage(request, context);
    dataSource.subscribe(dataSubscriber, UiThreadExecutorService.getInstance());
}
```

Comment: As we know, the resize option only works for jpeg, when it comes to png or gif and such stuff, fresco can't deal with it perfectly. So i just wanna resize the bitmap myself and load it by Fresco.But i don't know how to use fresco to load a bitmap not a uri. The reason why i wanna use Fresco to load it is to use it's cache.

Answer (score 4):

You would use Fresco's CacheKey directly for this:

```
public class DownloadVideoThumbnail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
private ImageView bmImage;
private Bitmap bitmapVideo;
private Context context;

public DownloadVideoThumbnail(Context context, ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = (ImageView) bmImage;
    this.context = context;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

    String urlStr = urls[0];
    if (readFromCacheSync(urlStr) == null) {
        try {
            //Your method call here
            bitmapVideo = retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(urlStr);

        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        bitmapVideo = readFromCacheSync(urlStr);
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    if (bitmapVideo != null) {
        //Load your bitmap here
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapVideo);
        bmImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    }
}


public void cacheBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String url) {
    try {
        CacheKey cacheKey = new SimpleCacheKey(url);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        final byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        Fresco.getImagePipelineFactory().getMainFileCache().insert(cacheKey, new WriterCallback() {
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
                outputStream.write(byteArray);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException cacheWriteException) {

    }
}

public static Bitmap readFromCacheSync(String imageUrl) {
    CacheKey cacheKey = DefaultCacheKeyFactory.getInstance().getEncodedCacheKey(ImageRequest.fromUri(imageUrl), null);
    StagingArea stagingArea = StagingArea.getInstance();
    EncodedImage encodedImage = stagingArea.get(cacheKey);
    if (encodedImage != null) {

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(encodedImage.getInputStream());
    }

    try {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(readFromDiskCache(cacheKey));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}


private static InputStream readFromDiskCache(final CacheKey key) throws IOException {
    try {
        FileCache fileCache = ImagePipelineFactory.getInstance().getMainFileCache();
        final BinaryResource diskCacheResource = fileCache.getResource(key);
        if (diskCacheResource == null) {
            FLog.v(TAG, "Disk cache miss for %s", key.toString());
            return null;
        }
        PooledByteBuffer byteBuffer;
        final InputStream is = diskCacheResource.openStream();
        FLog.v(TAG, "Successful read from disk cache for %s", key.toString());
        return is;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return null;
    }
}

public Bitmap retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath) throws Throwable {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
    try {
        mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
        else
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
        bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
        if (bitmap != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
            cacheBitmap(bitmap, videoPath);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Throwable(
                "Exception in retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)"
                        + e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null) {
            mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
}
```

Comment: super duper job..!

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution using Kotlin's coroutines:

```
suspend fun getBitmapFromUri(imageUri: Uri): Bitmap = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(imageUri).build()
    val dataSource = Fresco.getImagePipeline().fetchDecodedImage(imageRequest, this)
    val result = DataSources.waitForFinalResult(dataSource) as CloseableReference<CloseableBitmap>

    val bitmap = result.get().underlyingBitmap

    CloseableReference.closeSafely(result)
    dataSource.close()

    return@withContext bitmap
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use Fresco's image pipeline directly for this:

http://frescolib.org/docs/using-image-pipeline.html

Though if you don't mind my asking - what is the motivation here? Why do you need the Bitmap itself?

Comment: You might want to save the image on SD and write its path into a local `SQLight` database for example. You might also want the original resolution image for later purposes, while calling `.resize()` in the above example will give you a resized image (not sure if Fresco would do the same, but this is the reason why I was resizing images myself when using `Picasso`).

Comment: I'm sure that I will give Fresco a try in my new projects, but just to point it out - IMHO, accessing the downloaded image as a `Bitmap` object (or some other format you can directly manipulate) is an important feature many developers might want to see

Comment: I'll need the reference for creating a map marker for the Google Maps API (for an example)

Comment: @Kenny I need bitmap for maps too? Did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31563169/821173) answer I created a quick implementation that uses Kotlin extensions and RxJava to get a `ClosableBitmap` from an `ImageRequest`:

```
fun ImageRequest.getBitmap(context: Context): Maybe<CloseableReference<CloseableBitmap>> {
    val dataSource = Fresco.getImagePipeline().fetchDecodedImage(this, context)
    return Maybe.create { emitter ->
        dataSource.subscribe(
            object : BaseDataSubscriber<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>() {
                override fun onFailureImpl(dataSource: DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>) {
                    emitter.onComplete()
                }

                override fun onNewResultImpl(dataSource: DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>) {
                    if (!dataSource.isFinished) {
                        return
                    }

                    dataSource.result
                        ?.takeIf { it.get() is CloseableBitmap }
                        ?.let {
                            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                            emitter.onSuccess(it as CloseableReference<CloseableBitmap>)
                        }

                    emitter.onComplete()
                }
            },
            DefaultExecutorSupplier(1).forBackgroundTasks()
        )
    }
}
```

Since by contract it is required to close the reference once the bitmap has been used, I created this util function:

```
/**
 * The bitmap passed into [block] is only valid during the execution of the method.
 */
fun <T> CloseableReference<CloseableBitmap>.useBitmap(block: (Bitmap?) -> T): T? {
    return try {
        this.get()?.underlyingBitmap?.let { block(it) }
    } finally {
        CloseableReference.closeSafely(this)
    }
}
```