# Try to fetch bitmap from uri using Fresco

Tags: android, bitmap, fresco

Don't understand the behavior while I am fetching `Bitmap` using `Fresco` using `ImagePipeline`. When I debug my code it is executing `onNewResultImpl` or `onFailureImpl` and when I run the application is not working means it is not getting called `onFailureImpl` or `onNewResultImpl` (I am checking it using `Toast` and `Log` while running the app). I have seen this [SO Question and take ref from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476677/using-facebooks-fresco-to-load-a-bitmap)  and also [from `Fresco's` doc.](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-image-pipeline.html#_)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACTION_OPEN_GALLERY:
                mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                    commentImgView.setImageURI(mImageCaptureUri);//mImageCaptureUri is working fine
                    try {
                        imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder
                                .newBuilderWithSource(mImageCaptureUri)
                                .setRequestPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                                .setLowestPermittedRequestLevel(ImageRequest.RequestLevel.FULL_FETCH)
                                .build();
                        dataSource = imagePipeline.fetchDecodedImage(imageRequest, CommentActivity.this);
                        dataSource.subscribe(new BaseBitmapDataSubscriber() {
                            @Override
                            protected void onNewResultImpl(@Nullable Bitmap bitmap) {
                                if (bitmap != null) {
                                    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
                                    Log.d("Bitmap ","after callback");
                                    Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this,"has bitmap",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("Bitmap is null ","after callback");
                                    Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this,"bitmap is null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onFailureImpl(DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> dataSource) {
                                Log.d("Bitmap ","after callback failure");
                                Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this,"Failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }, CallerThreadExecutor.getInstance());
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (dataSource != null) {
                            dataSource.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I am trying to get bitmap from **jpg image** not from any **animated gif** image

Comment: try declaring `imageRequest, imagePipeline and dataSource ` to class level

Comment: make sure you are using latest library files and jar files

Comment: what values does `data` variable contain? make sure you are retriving correct values

Comment: no I haven't. didn't need while picasso and glide are around. but had made some demo earlier

Comment: there is a bit of problem using glide because it resize the bitmap as per imageview's height width

Comment: need to check fresco out, will try making a demo for this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have removed `try` and `finally` block and and closing the `Datasource` inside `onNewResultImpl` and `onFailureImpl`

code snippet

```
ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder
                            .newBuilderWithSource(mImageCaptureUri)
                            .setAutoRotateEnabled(true)
                            .build();

ImagePipeline imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline();
final DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>>
                            dataSource = imagePipeline.fetchDecodedImage(imageRequest, this);

dataSource.subscribe(new BaseBitmapDataSubscriber() {

      @Override
      public void onNewResultImpl(@Nullable Bitmap bitmap) {
         if (dataSource.isFinished() && bitmap != null){
                  Log.d("Bitmap","has come");
                  bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
                  dataSource.close();
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailureImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        if (dataSource != null) {
                dataSource.close();
        }
     }
 }, CallerThreadExecutor.getInstance());
```

Comment: Wonder why you need `Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap)` instead of simply `bmp = bitmap`?

Comment: That is not full code I was scaling the bitmap there and assigned that to bmp