# Provide Only bitmap to Glide Not url

Tags: android, android-glide

i have list of video Urls. i create thumbnails from them. These thumbnails are in form of bitmap.so what i tried

```
Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(bitmap)
                    .into(mVideoThumbnail)
```

What i found from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867322/using-glide-to-load-bitmap-into-imageview).We can do something like this.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(url).asBitmap()
                    .into(mVideoThumbnail)
```

But above function is used for loading URL as bitmap. It doesn't take bitmap as parameter.

i also know that i can set directly bitmap into image as below mentioned

```
mVideoThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Above method works fine if i have to set thumbnail for single video but in case of multiple videos, it cause some performance issue.

**i am sharing my code for fetching thumbnail as a bitmap and set into my ImageView. Is There any way to pass directly bitmap to Glide or any other options are available for reducing performance issue. Please Help**

```
public class TopicInstructionViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
@BindView(R.id.iv_thumbnail)
ImageView mVideoThumbnail;
@BindView(R.id.iv_play_video)
ImageView mVideoPlayIcon;
@BindView(R.id.tv_instruction_name)
TextView mInstructionName;
private ITopicVideoPlayListener mTopicVideoPlayListener;
private Context mContext;
private String videoPath;
private int instructionId;
private boolean mHasVideoSeenBL;

public TopicInstructionViewHolder(View itemView,
                                  ITopicVideoPlayListener mTopicVideoPlayListener,
                                  Context mContext) {
    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    this.mTopicVideoPlayListener = mTopicVideoPlayListener;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public void setData(TopicInstructionDetail topicInstructionDetail) {

    String thumbnailPath = null;
    TopicInstructionTranslationDetail topicInstructionTranslationDetails = findTopicInstructionAsPerLang(topicInstructionDetail.getmTopicInstructionTranslationDetails());
    mVideoPlayIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
    videoPath = topicInstructionTranslationDetails.getmInstructionPath();
    mHasVideoSeenBL = topicInstructionDetail.isCompleteSeen();
    instructionId = topicInstructionTranslationDetails.getmInstructionId();
    mInstructionName.setText(topicInstructionTranslationDetails.getmInstructionName());
    thumbnailPath = (NetworkConstants.VIDEO_URL + topicInstructionTranslationDetails.getmThumbnailPath());

    new SampleAsyncTask().execute(NetworkConstants.VIDEO_URL+videoPath);
    if (topicInstructionDetail.isCompleteSeen()) {
        mVideoPlayIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
    } else {
        mVideoPlayIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
    }

}

private TopicInstructionTranslationDetail findTopicInstructionAsPerLang(List<TopicInstructionTranslationDetail> topicInstructionTranslationDetails) {

    TopicInstructionTranslationDetail topicInstructionTranslationDetail = null;
    for (TopicInstructionTranslationDetail topicTranslation : topicInstructionTranslationDetails) {
        if (topicTranslation.getmLanguage().equals(AppPreferencesHelper.getInstance(mContext).getCurrentUserLanguage())) {
            topicInstructionTranslationDetail = topicTranslation;
        }
    }

    if (topicInstructionTranslationDetail == null) {
        topicInstructionTranslationDetail = findDefaultTopicInstruction(topicInstructionTranslationDetails);
    }
    return topicInstructionTranslationDetail;
}

private TopicInstructionTranslationDetail findDefaultTopicInstruction(List<TopicInstructionTranslationDetail> topicInstructionTranslationDetails) {

    TopicInstructionTranslationDetail topicInstructionDetail = null;
    for (TopicInstructionTranslationDetail topicTranslation : topicInstructionTranslationDetails) {
        if (topicTranslation.getmLanguage().equals(LanguageCode.getLanguageCode(LanguageCode.LANGUAGE_FIRST))) {
            topicInstructionDetail = topicTranslation;
        }
    }
    return topicInstructionDetail;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    mTopicVideoPlayListener.playVideo(videoPath, instructionId, mHasVideoSeenBL);
}
```

//fetching bitmap from video url
    private class SampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
        try {
            mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(strings[0], new HashMap<String, String>());
            } else {
                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            }
            bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(1, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null) {
                mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            mVideoThumbnail.setImageBitmap(s);
           /* Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(s).asBitmap()
                    .into(mVideoThumbnail);*/
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Use Fresco Library instead of Glide.**

You can use facebook [fresco](http://frescolib.org/) library instead of glide for smooth and efficient loading in list. Fresco library have [pipeline](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-image-pipeline.html) techniques for loading the image thumbnail in list. Use Asynctask and fresco pipeline to get the Thumbnail from video and load it.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49755325/5423894), implemented solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Glide v3. Glide v4 did add an option for loading `Bitmap` as `Drawable`. Docs [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/460/com/bumptech/glide/RequestManager.html#load-android.graphics.Bitmap-)

Update to v4 require some more configuration, check [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html)